# Symbolizer with external GIF image is not rendered pixel-perfect

Tags: geotools, rendering

We want to pinpoint some locations on a map with some external GIF symbolizers. The issue we have is visible in the attached image*: looks like somethings happens on a sub-pixel level, so that the resulting pluses look mutated :), most of them are somehow distorted/blurred/interpolated. The original external GIF is shown in the right lower corner of the image* (simple and sharp 5x5 pixel "+" symbol).

Original image:

[image]

Magnified image:

[image]

Update: Same thing happens with well known symbolizers (e.g. MARK_CROSS):

```
...
final Mark mark = sb.createMark(StyleBuilder.MARK_CROSS, Color.red, Color.yellow, 1);
final Graphic graphics = sb.createGraphic(null, mark, null, 1, 10, 0);
final Style style2 = sb.createStyle(sb.createPointSymbolizer(graphics));
...
```

[image]